# Oracle import from 18c to 12c

Tags: oracle

I'm exporting database from oracle version 18c and importing it on oracle version is 12.1. I encounter below error while importing.

*Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Automatic Storage Management option
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39142: incompatible version number 5.1 in dump file "/backup/dumps/RB-umps/CALYPSO_DEV2_2021.dmp"*

I've used parameter version=12.1 while exporting the database.

Is there any compatibility issue between oracle 18c (18.12) & 12.1 ? Anyone face this error ?

Comment: Off-topic for this site. But... are you sure your export specified version 12.1, not 12.2? The internal version 5.1 would suggest 12.2 was used.

Comment: @AlexPoole : Yes we export using varsion=12.1 from 18c. Dump version of 12.1 is 4.1 and 18c is 5.1, so is there any incompatibility issue between 12.1 & 18c ?

Comment: It sounds like the version parameter isn't being used, or is being reset to compatible later in the export command. Might be helpful to include the full export and import commands. But still off-topic really.

Comment: As suggested, please update your question to include the full export and import commands that you are using.